# Is there a way to copy a vector of derived class pointers without casting it to the base class?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, stdvector

I have 4 classes: 1 `Base`, 2 `Derived`s and 1 `Container` class.
The `Container` class holds a vector of `Base` pointers.

I want to create a copy constructor for my class `Container` that doesn't cast the `Derived` pointers to a `Base`, so that I can cast the `Base` pointers to `Derived` pointers afterwards.

```
class Base {
   int m_base_attribute;
public:
   Base() : m_base_attribute(420) {}

   virtual void say_hello() {
      std::cout << "Hello !" << std::endl;
   }
};
```

```
class Derived : public Base {
   int m_derived_attribute;
public:
   Derived() : Base(), m_derived_attribute(69) {}

   virtual void say_hello() {
      std::cout << "I'm a derived class !" << std::endl;
   }
};
```

```
class Container {
   std::vector<Base*> m_base_vector;
public:
   Container() {
      m_base_vector.push_back(new Derived());
   }

   Container(const Container& model) {
      for(auto base : model.m_base_vector){
         m_base_vector.push_back(new Base(*base));
      }
   }

   ~Container() {
      for(auto base : m_base_vector) {
         delete base;
      }
   }
};
```

Is there a way to do it without any memory leaks?

Comment: Your problem isn't memory leaks, it's slicing. (Also, lack of virtual destructors, but that may just be your example code.) You need a virtual `clone()` function in your base class that correctly copies the object.

Comment: Ah okay. And will it use the right version of the function intelligently, or do I have to cast it to something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `new Base(*base)` always creates a `Base` object, never a `Derived` object.  This is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626).  The workaround is to use a virtual `clone` function and a virtual destructor:

```
class Base {
    int m_base_attribute;
public:
    // ...
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<Base>(*this);
    }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int m_derived_attribute;
public:
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this);
    }
};
```

Note that I used `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers to avoid memory leaks.  Now you can implement the `Container` class without slicing:

```
class Container {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> m_base_vector;
public:
    // ...    
    Container(const Container& model)
    {
        m_base_vector.reserve(model.m_base_vector.size());
        for (const auto& p : m_base_vector) {
            m_base_vector.push_back(p->clone());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The way you have declared `clone()` means that objects can still be sliced - all it takes is for one derived class to not override the `clone()` function.   That type of error can be avoided by making `Base` an abstract class, with the `clone()` function pure virtual.    That forces derived classes to override the `clone()`  (otherwise the derived class cannot be instantiated) and helps prevent unintended slicing.

Comment: @Peter That doesn’t solve the problem completely though - I can still derive from a derived class and forget to implement clone().

Comment: While that's true, it is also a reason that a lot of design and coding guidelines specifically disallow deriving from non-abstract classes.

Comment: @Peter While that’s also true, there is also a lot of code that does not follow such guidelines. So I’ll leave this decision to the OP.